# creatRuleViolation how to define it? Save me from this

Tags: java, plugins, javadoc, pmd

Help. I would like to sacrifice the reputation for a proper answer..

```
public class ParameterNameConvention extends AbstractJavaRule {

private final static String PATTERN = "[p][a-zA-Z]+";

    public Object visit(ASTMethodDeclaration node, Object data) {
        RuleContext result = (RuleContext) data;
        String rulePattern = (!getStringProperty("rulePattern")
                .equalsIgnoreCase("")) ? getStringProperty("rulePattern")
                : PATTERN;
        if (node.containsChildOfType(ASTFormalParameter.class)) {
            Iterator iterator = node.findChildrenOfType(
                    ASTFormalParameter.class).iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                ASTFormalParameter element = (ASTFormalParameter) iterator
                        .next();
                Iterator decIdIterator = element.findChildrenOfType(
                        ASTVariableDeclaratorId.class).iterator();
                while (decIdIterator.hasNext()) {
                    ASTVariableDeclaratorId decElement = (ASTVariableDeclaratorId) decIdIterator
                            .next();
                    if (!decElement.getImage().matches(rulePattern)) {

                        result.getReport()
                                .addRuleViolation(
                                        createRuleViolation(
                                                this,
                                                node.getBeginLine(),
                                                "Parameter '"
                                                        + decElement.getImage()
                                                        + "' should match regular expression pattern '"
                                                        + rulePattern + "'",
                                                result));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, 'creatRuleViolation' doesn't work. How to define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, I did a bit of research last night to help you out.
`createRuleViolation()` is defined in `AbstractRuleViolationFactory` as abstract and implemented in language specific factory sub-classes (eg: `JavaRuleViolationFactory`), not directly available in Rule classes hierarchy.

Instead use `addViolationWithMessage()` method that is inherited from `AbstractRule` via `AbstractJavaRule`. This method eventually calls the create method on appropriate factory at runtime.

I tried your code with latest PMD version 5.0.3, and required few more tweaks other than the issue with`createRuleViolation()` method to get it working. Mainly to navigate from MethodDeclaration node to Parameter nodes, there could be a better way though, but it works now. I have modified the code based on the AST (abstract source tree).

```
package madhav.pmd.rule;

import net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleContext;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTFormalParameter;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTFormalParameters;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTMethodDeclaration;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTMethodDeclarator;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTVariableDeclaratorId;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.rule.AbstractJavaRule;

public class ParameterNameConvention extends AbstractJavaRule
{
    private final static String PATTERN = "[p][a-zA-Z]+";

    @Override
    public Object visit(final ASTMethodDeclaration node, final Object pData)
    {
        final RuleContext result = (RuleContext) pData;
        // TODO : get property
        final String rulePattern = PATTERN;
        final ASTMethodDeclarator methodDecNode = node.getFirstChildOfType(ASTMethodDeclarator.class);
        final ASTFormalParameters paramsNode = methodDecNode.getFirstChildOfType(ASTFormalParameters.class);
        if (paramsNode.getParameterCount() > 0)
        {
            for (final ASTFormalParameter element : paramsNode.findChildrenOfType(ASTFormalParameter.class))
            {
                for (final ASTVariableDeclaratorId decElement : element.findChildrenOfType(ASTVariableDeclaratorId.class))
                {
                    if (!decElement.getImage().matches(rulePattern))
                    {
                        addViolationWithMessage(result, node,
                                "Parameter '"
                                        + decElement.getImage()
                                        + "' should match regular expression pattern '"
                                        + rulePattern + "'",
                                node.getBeginLine(),
                                node.getEndLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

To test the rule on the same class, I named one parameter to satisfy the rule and one not to satisfy (`final ASTMethodDeclaration node, final Object pData`).

The ruleset xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="My rules">
  <description>My test rules</description>
  <rule name="ParameterNameConvention"
        message="Parameter must start with p"
        class="madhav.pmd.rule.ParameterNameConvention">
    <description>Don't use non-complaint parameters </description>

    <example>
        <![CDATA[
         void methodX(int value)
        ]]>
    </example>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

The result xml PMD generated is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmd version="5.0.3" timestamp="2013-06-13T16:03:52.404">
    <file name="D:\Projects\ZRules\src\madhav\pmd\rule\ParameterNameConvention.java">
        <violation beginline="16" endline="43" begincolumn="16" endcolumn="9" 
            rule="ParameterNameConvention" ruleset="My rules" package="madhav.pmd.rule" 
            class="ParameterNameConvention" priority="5">
                Parameter node should match regular expression pattern [p][a-zA-Z]+
        </violation>
    </file>
</pmd>
```

For more details on running PMD standalone from command line see the documentation on PMD website or there is loads available if you google around.

Hope this is helpful.