# How to write new rules of PMD for eclipse using

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle, pmd, rule

i followed the PMD official docs to create a new rule of PMD.(actually, the docs is out of date and had misled me ) neverTheless,the new rule which i created can only use by pmd.bat.it can not worke in eclipse pmd plugin.who can tell me how to do ? the problem confuse me a few days.Thanks a lot!

Comment: See if this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068159/pmd-creatruleviolation-how-to-define-it-save-me-from-this/17091151#17091151)

Comment: thank you .madhav-turangi. but i think you may not understand what i mean.luckily,i found the answer this morning.if you interesting about it,here is the artical  [link](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/).anyway,thank you !